# Making text more visible&noticeable on texture?

Tags: texturing

I made a model that is covered with a transparent glossy surface.

Under that surface I placed 2 bars that are emitting light, and a layer that has custom texture on it (which has numbers on it)

[image]

As you see the numbers are faded and not well lighted, even though I’ve placed the bars besides it.

How could I improve its look to be more outstanding and easier to see?

I made a normal map for the texture and it is a bit 3d-like now, but still isn’t the best.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just fake the emission by texture?

[image: fake]

Should be more easier than making the light actually penetrating the glass with less and simple light path.

Comment: Oh Hikariztw thank you very very much! You're awesome!